# Solving $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2\cos(x)}\right)}{\sin(\sin(x^2))}$

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

> **I've been asked to solve the limit.**
> $$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2\cos(x)}\right)}{\sin(\sin(x^2))}$$

---

**Here's my approach:**
$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2\cos(x)}\right)}{\sin(\sin(x^2))}$$

Using the identity, $\cos(x) =\sin(90^{\circ} - x)$

\begin{aligned}\implies \lim_{x\to0}\frac{\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2\cos(x)}\right)}{\sin(\sin(x^2))} 
& = \lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2} - \frac{\pi}{2\cos(x)}\right)}{\sin(\sin(x^2))}
\\& = \lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2} - \dfrac{\pi}{2\cos(x)}\right)\cdot\dfrac{\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2} - \frac{\pi}{2\cos(x)}\right)}{\left(\frac{\pi}{2} - \frac{\pi}{2\cos(x)}\right)}}{\sin(\sin(x^2))}
\\ & = \lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{\left(\dfrac{\pi}{2} - \dfrac{\pi}{2\cos(x)}\right)}{\sin(\sin(x^2))}\cdot \underbrace{\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2} - \frac{\pi}{2\cos(x)}\right)}{\left(\frac{\pi}{2} - \frac{\pi}{2\cos(x)}\right)}}_{1}
\\ & = \dfrac{\lim\limits_{x\to0}\dfrac{\pi}{2}\left(\dfrac{\cos(x) - 1}{\cos(x)}\right)}{\underbrace{\lim\limits_{x\to0}\dfrac{\sin(\sin(x^2))}{\sin(x^2)}}_1\cdot\sin(x^2)}
\\ & =\dfrac{\lim\limits_{x\to0}\dfrac{\pi}{2}\left(\dfrac{\cos(x) - 1}{\cos(x)}\right)}{\underbrace{\lim\limits_{x\to0}\dfrac{\sin(x^2)}{x^2}}_1\cdot x^2}
\\ & =  \color{blue}{\boxed{\lim\limits_{x\to0}\dfrac{\pi}{2x^2}\left(\dfrac{\cos(x) - 1}{\cos(x)}\right)}}
\end{aligned}

Now, I'm unable to think of anything to do with this boxed part. Can anyone check my above method and tell me what to do further with this question? Any other shorter method is also most welcomed!

Comment: +1 just for typing the body!

Comment: Do you know about taylor expansions ?

Comment: @Atmos I know, but not much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\frac{\cos x - 1}{x^2}
 = \frac{\cos x - 1}{x^2} \times \frac{\cos x + 1}{\cos x + 1}
 = \frac{\cos^2 x - 1}{x^2(\cos x + 1)}
 = \frac{-\sin^2 x}{x^2} \times \frac{1}{\cos x + 1}
$$
and the left fraction can be computed since $\sin(x)/x \to 1$...

Answer (score 2):

You have $\sin(x^2)=x^2+o(x^2)$ and therefore also
$$
\sin(\sin(x^2))=x^2+o(x^2)
$$
Thus you need the Taylor expansion of
$$
\cos\Bigl(\frac{\pi}{2\cos x}\Bigr)
$$
up to degree $2$. Consider $f(x)=1/\cos x$. Then $f(0)=1$ and
$$
f'(x)=\frac{\sin x}{\cos^2x},\qquad f'(0)=0
$$
and
$$
f''(x)=\frac{\cos^3x+2\sin^2x\cos x}{\cos^4x}=\frac{\cos^2x+2\sin^2x}{\cos^3x},\qquad f''(0)=1
$$
Hence
$$
\frac{\pi}{2\cos x}=\frac{\pi}{2}+\frac{\pi}{4}x^2+o(x^2)
$$
and therefore
$$
\cos\Bigl(\frac{\pi}{2\cos x}\Bigr)=
\cos\Bigl(\frac{\pi}{2}+\frac{\pi}{4}x^2+o(x^2)\Bigr)=-\sin\Bigl(\frac{\pi}{4}x^2+o(x^2)\Bigr)=-\frac{\pi}{4}x^2+o(x^2)
$$
and your limit is
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{-\pi x^2/4+o(x^2)}{x^2+o(x^2)}=-\frac{\pi}{4}
$$

Comment: For my master at here and at Tex site!

Answer (score 2):

I found another way to compute the final boxed limit.
$$\begin{aligned}&\lim_{x\to0} \frac{\pi}{2x^2}\cdot\frac{\cos(x)-1}{\cos(x)}\\=&\lim_{x\to0}\frac{-(1-\cos(x))}{x^2}\cdot\frac{\pi}{2\cos(x)}\end{aligned}$$

The limit $\boxed{\lim\limits_{x\to0}\dfrac{1-\cos(x)}{x^2} = \dfrac12}$

$$\begin{aligned}\implies& \lim_{x\to0}\frac{-(1-\cos(x))}{x^2}\cdot\frac{\pi}{2\cos(x)} = \lim_{x\to0}\frac{-1}{2}\cdot\frac{\pi}{2\cos(x)}\\=&\frac{-\pi}{4\cos(0)} = \frac{-\pi}{4}\end{aligned}$$

So the limit is $-\pi/4$.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\cos\left(x\right)-1 \underset{(0)}{=}-\frac{x^2}{2}+o\left(x^3\right)
$$
Hence combined with what you did
$$
\frac{\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2\cos(x)}\right)}{\sin(\sin(x^2))} \underset{(0)}{\sim}\frac{\pi}{2x^2}\left(-\frac{x^2}{2}\right) = -\frac{\pi}{4}$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm unable to actually understand some of the symbols used by you in the solution.

Comment: The (0) underneath the first equation is a label. Then the second (0) indicates the OP used the equation labelled (0) in that step. And the little $o(x^3)$ is little-oh notation, indicating terms tending to zero at least as quickly as $x^3$

Comment: $\sim$ just means the ratio of the two expressions tends to $1$ as $x$ tends to the number just below (here $0$)